# How to implement angular 6 , 7 custom scheduler for drivers?

Tags: node.js, angular

I need to create an angular scheduler like an attached picture in angular 6 or 7, I only know the basics of angular.
I also tried this component [angular scheduler](https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-scheduler/), but I don't know how to show the names on the left side instead of time and other things.

Can someone please help me? How can I show name, status list on the left side and other things.

[image]

Thanks in advance :(

Answer (score 0):

Can please check syncfusion angular scheduler https://www.syncfusion.com/angular-ui-components/angular-scheduler

Look at this example https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/schedule/timeline-resource it will match your requirement.

Also refer following UG link https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/schedule/getting-started/

Comment: But i think syncfusion is third party we need pay for this.